# Criar um link que ao ser clicado pego o seu texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que tem o ID do Material e o Nome, o nome é um link, preciso fazer com que quando eu clicar no link ele pegue o ID e o nome o coloque em um campo de texto no fomulário.

A tabela é gerada dinamicamente por um script

```
$('#tbl').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"ids\">" + item.ID +
                        "</td><td class=\"nome\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Seleciona()\">" + item.Nome + "<\a></td></tr>")
```

Estou tentando pegar o texto do link assim:

```
function Seleciona(event) {
    var id = event.ID
    var nome = event.Nome

    $('#ID').val(ID);
    $('#nome').val(nome);

    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: Esse código está a precisar de umas correções.. Quando fazes o `append` tens tags mal, não estás a enviar nada para a função `Seleciona`

Comment: o que devo passar para a função Seleciona?

Comment: já fiz uma resposta com as edições necessárias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é você já pré carregar o seu link passando os valores para o método `Seleciona`.

*Veja Funcionando:*

```js
   $(function () {
            $('#tbl').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"ids\">" + 1 +
            "</td><td class=\"nome\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Seleciona('"+1+"',"+ "'Teste')\">" + "Teste" + "<\a></td></tr>")

        });
        function Seleciona(id, nome) {
            $('#ID').val(id);
            $('#nome').val(nome);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
    </table>
    <input type="text" id="ID" />
    <input type="text" id="nome" />
```

Comment: e de forma simples. +1

Comment: @CesarMiguel a sua está bem prática tbm. Obrigado.

Comment: Em tabelas mais complexas é capaz de ser melhor, mas para o que o Alan quer não justifica :P

Answer (score 3):

Na construção da tua tabela envias o teu `item.ID` principal que vai definir cada `td` (também tinhas uns erros nas tags):

```
$('#tbl').append("<tr class=\"corpoTbl\"> <td class=\"ids\" id=\"tdID_" + item.ID +">" + item.ID +
                        "</td><td class=\"nome\" id=\"tdNome_" + item.ID +"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Seleciona('"+ item.ID +"')\">" + item.Nome + "</a></td></tr>")
```

Na função `Seleciona` recebes um `idlinha` que corresponde ao teu `item.ID`, para poder tratar de ir buscar os dados do `id` e do `nome` :

```
function Seleciona (idlinha) {
    var id = $("#tdID_" + idlinha).html();
    var nome = $("#tdNome_"+idlinha+" a").text();   

    $('#inp_ID').val(id);
    $('#inp_Nome').val(nome);

    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

Exemplo funcional:

```js
Seleciona = function (idlinha) {
    var id = $("#tdID_" + idlinha).html();
    var nome = $("#tdNome_"+idlinha+" a").text();   

    $('#inp_ID').val(id);
    $('#inp_Nome').val(nome);

    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr class="corpoTbl"> 
        <td class="ids" id="tdID_12">12</td>
        <td class="nome" id="tdNome_12">
            <a href="#" onclick="Seleciona(12)">Fernando Trambolho</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="inp_ID"/>
<input type="text" id="inp_Nome"/>
```