# Obter valores das colunas de uma tabela e salvar o valor da cada coluna em um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma tabela com 2 colunas e gostaria de, ao clicar em alguma linha, atribuir os valores de cada coluna desta linha clicada em um `<input type="text" />`.
Tenho um código que ele atribui porém se eu clico na primeira coluna ele atribui o valor da primeira coluna ou o da segunda. Como é que separo isso?

```
$('#tableTime tr td').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    $("#descricaoAgenda").val(content);
});
```

Comment: Fernando, para que não haja confusão no entendimento de sua pergunta, sugiro que poste também teu HTML e tente descrever com mais detalhes o que você está tentando fazer. :)

Comment: Tinha colocado a respsta errada, mais se tiver montado seu html em tempo de execução aqui você pode ter uma noção de como fazer. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65204/criar-um-link-que-ao-ser-clicado-pego-o-seu-texto/65209#65209

Comment: coloquei o html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso utilize o [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) para selecionar a `tr` pai da `td`que foi clicada, depois de acessar a `tr` use a função [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para selecionar as `td's` filhas e utilize o seletor [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) para selecionar cada coluna da linha selecionada.

```
$('#tableTime tr td').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).parent().find(':nth-child(1)').text();
    $("#descricaoAgenda").val(content);
});
```

> **Dica**: Você pode utilizar o evento click diretamente na linha da tabela `$('table tr').on('click', callback)`, dessa forma, você não precisará utilizar o `parent()`.

Veja o exemplo alterado conforme a **dica**, sem utilizar o `parent`

```js
$('table tr').on('click', function() {
  var content1 = $(this).find(':nth-child(1)').text();
  var content2 = $(this).find(':nth-child(2)').text();
  $("#txtResultado1").val(content1);
  $("#txtResultado2").val(content2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="txtResultado1" />
<input type="text" id="txtResultado2" />
```

Comment: eu preciso pegar o elemento da <td> e nao da <tr>. por exemplo: ao clicar na linha (em qualquer lugar dela) enviar o texto da segunda coluna para um input.

Comment: Na sua pergunta você disse que precisa "atribuir os valores de cada coluna desta linha". Da maneira que respondi, isso é o que irá acontecer. O que você realmente quer é pegar apenas o valor da última coluna da linha seleciona, isso?

Comment: sim.. só que separadamente.. eu testei a forma que você me passou, só que foi o valor da linha inteira e não cada valor em um input diferente

Comment: Entendi agora o que vcê precisa de fato. Já posto a solução editada.

Comment: muito bom!! era isso mesmo.. eu cheguei perto só faltou colocar o .parent haha.. mas valeu

Comment: +1 grande resposta.