# Obter ID da linha da tabela para carregar Modal para edital

Tags: php, ajax, modal

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Depois de tanta pesquisa e não conseguir entender como funciona, estou tentando solucionar um problema que estou tendo.

Estou criando um cadastro de prestadores de serviço, porém me deparei na falta de conhecimento:

Criei uma table que carrega os dados dos prestadores com uma coluna com os botões de alterar / remover.

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>CPF</th>
                                    <th>RG</th>
                                    <th>Telefone</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <i class='fa fa-pencil fa-fw'></i>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <i class='fa fa-remove fa-fw'></i>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <i class='fa fa-sign-out fa-0.5x'></i>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <thead>
                               <tbody>
                               <?php include ("resultado.php"); ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Abaixo criei um modal para abrir uma janela para alterar os dados do prestador com base no ID dele que será obtida da linha selecionada, todo o HTML se encontra em um PHP que é chamada internamente no modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalAlterar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                  <?php include "prestadores_alterar.php"?>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                            </div>
```

A pergunta é, como consigo carregar esse modal com os dados da linha que estão no banco de dados?

Desde já agradeço muito pela ajuda.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como você carrega sua tabela? Uma sugestão seria +- igual ao dessa pergunta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65204/criar-um-link-que-ao-ser-clicado-pego-o-seu-texto/65209#65209

Comment: 1 faz a conexão com o banco, 2 faz uma query para selecionar os dados, 3 põe o resultado da query no modal. São essas suas dificuldades?